# Point of putting a function in a var -JS

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

What's the point of putting a function in a var or not?

```
var varFunc = function () {/*cool code*/};
function plainFunc() {
    /*cooler code?*/
}
```

Comment: do you mean as opposed to just naming the function or as opposed to using anonymous functions?

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a function to a variable, aka anonymous functions, can be pretty useful once you know what they do.

Check this out - http://helephant.com/2008/08/23/javascript-anonymous-functions/

Comment: But once it's assigned to a variable, it's no longer "anonymous" (consider that all "named" functions are simply function-objects accessed with a given property or variable name and their "name" is thus simply in how they are accessed).